# Perl strings and < & > operators

Tags: perl, operators, string-comparison

For comparing strings, the use is usually lt,gt etc..

what exactly perl does when I compare strings using numerical operators? (<, >)

```
my $str1 = 'Joe';
my $str2 = 'flight';
```

I guess that when doing `$str1 gt $str2` perl compares the ASCII codes(?), but what happens when I do the following:

```
$str1 > $str2
```

thanks

Comment: You get the equivalent of '0 > 0'. Add 'use warnings;' to your code, and you'll also get a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Perl, 10 is 10 whether it's stored as a string (PV), a signed int (IV), an unsigned int (UV) or a floating point number (NV).

`<`, `>` and `==` compare the numerical values of their operands. Then numerical value of stuff that isn't a number is zero*, so the numerical value of `flight` is zero (with a warning) and the numerical value of `Joe` is zero (with a warning), so they are equal.

On the other hand, the numerical value of string `10` is 10, and the numerical value of string `2` is 2, so

```
10 >= 2       # True
'10' >= '2'   # True

10 ge 2       # False (ord('1') is less than ord('2'))
'10' ge '2'   # False
```

* — Objects can override this, and the numerical value of a reference is the address of the referenced value.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you got a warning :

```
Argument "flight" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) at 
Argument "Joe" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) at
```

Then perl cast these strings to integer so they become 0 then the comparison is done.

Comment: Well, you should get a warning. For some reason `use strict; use warnings;` is still escaping some people's boilerplate.

Comment: Its not, I'm using these pair always, was just wondering what happens behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

```
what exactly perl does when I compare strings using numerical operators? (<, >)
```

perl converts the strings to numbers before comparing them.

Both of your example strings convert to zero.

```
but what happens when I do the following:
$str1 > $str2
```

They are compared according to the "collating sequence" (nominally alphabetical),
as if the strings were sorted as in a phonebook.

```
'barney' < 'bammbam'
```

is false:

```
compare 1st letters - tied
compare 2nd letters - tied
compare 3rd letters - "m" comes before "r", so the comparison is false.
```

Comment: No, it simply compares the codepoints of the characters. If you want phonebook order, you need to use `use locale;`

Comment: `'barney' < 'bammbam'` is a numeric comparison.  I think you meant `'barney' lt 'bammbam'`.